# How to add image to scale?

Tags: java, swt

I want to add image to the min value and to the max value.

The idea that the scanner will have two icons of + and - and text in the - area and text in the plus area

for example 
Zoom out (- icon).............Zoom in (+ icon)

How I can add images?

```
 final Scale scale = new Scale (fComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    Rectangle clientArea = fComposite.getClientArea ();
    scale.setBounds (clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 200, 64);
    scale.setMaximum (4);
    scale.setPageIncrement (1);
    scale.setSelection(4);


    scale.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
          public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    .....
          }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: BTW: Never use absolute sizes (unless absolutely necessary), use `Layout`s instead. Please read this: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by SWT.

However, you can just place a `Label`/`CLabel` with an `Image` to both sides of the `Scale`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Composite scaleComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    scaleComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    CLabel leftImage = new CLabel(scaleComp, SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    leftImage.setText("Left");
    leftImage.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_ERROR));
    leftImage.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));

    final Scale scale = new Scale (scaleComp, SWT.NONE);
    scale.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    scale.setMaximum (4);
    scale.setPageIncrement (1);
    scale.setSelection(4);

    CLabel rightImage = new CLabel(scaleComp, SWT.NONE);
    rightImage.setText("Right");
    rightImage.setImage(display.getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_INFORMATION));
    rightImage.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.FILL, false, true));

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: is it possible to add comment near to the icons ?

Comment: I am new in the java UI i want to add text before each icon how i can do it ?

Comment: @user1365697 Updated my answer. You can change the position by changing the second parameter in the `CLabel` constructor.